# set variable to first word in text-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to read the output of `FIND /n "some text" a_file` to store the first line number in a variable...

Let's say the file content is:

> ```
> [342]>>> (1-WARNING) Variable ANAME assigned but never read
> [343]>>> (2-ERROR) Too few ENDWHILEs, 1 WHILE command(s) not terminated
> ```

I read the file using:

```
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in (found.txt) do (if "%%a" neq "" set l=%%a & echo a = %%a & echo l = %l%)
```

from `echo` command, I see the variable `%%a` having the right value, but it's not assigned to `l`

Any suggestions to get the value into `l`?

Comment: You might want to investigate [Delayed Expansion of Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work as expected, because you would need to enable and to apply [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are writing and reading a variable in the same block of code.

Anyway, I would do that like this (there is actually no need to store the result of `find` into `found.exe` when you let `for /F` parse the output of `find` immediately):

```cmd
set "WORD="
for /F "delims=[]" %%A in ('^< "a_file" find /N "some text"') do (
    if not defined WORD set "WORD=%%A"
)
```

The variable `WORD` (I do not like variable names like `l` consisting of only a single letter) is assigned in the first loop iteration only because of the `if defined` query (for this to work the variable needs to be cleared initially).

Or like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=[]" %%A in ('^< "a_file" find /N "some text"') do (
    set "WORD=%%A"
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
```

The loop is left after the first iteration, because `goto` breaks block or loop contexts.
This is the recommended variant for huge text files.

Comment: Slight modification needed, to avoid the first line output from FIND command.

for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n ">>> " a_file ^| find /v "----------"') do ( if not defined line set line=%%a )

Comment: No, because I used input redirection (`<`; escaped like `^<` as used within `for /F`)...

Answer (score 0):

I find this more straightforward using a regex in PowerShell. The square brackets must be escaped because they are used in a regex to specify a character set.

```
Get-Content -Path './firstword.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '\[(\d+)\]') {
            $thenumber = $matches[1]

            $thenumber
        }
    }
```